# Using the queue listener for xml messages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to retrieve messages pushed from Amazon in XML format via a Amazon SQS queue with laravel 5.1's queue:listen command, but get an error saying

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job::resolveAndFire() must be of the type array, null given, called in /opt/PhpstormProjects/Amazon_Requester/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/SqsJob.php on line 52 and defined

So I looked into above class where it the job is called via the fire method:

```
$this->resolveAndFire(json_decode($this->getRawBody(), true));
```

The problem here is that json_decode(...) returns `null`, but when I dump the message's data, I get the xml response as expected.

If I would change the way the listener handles my response, I couldn't update laravel anymore without breaking my code, so I'm in doubt if there's any other way to tell laravel how to handle the response?

Comment: Can you show us your code for creating the job?

Comment: I'm not creating the job. @ceejayoz It's pushed onto my queue directly from amazon, I do only listen for new messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's queue expects the queue items to come from Laravel. Queue items contain a JSON payload with info on which handler to run, what data to pass to it, etc. If you want to listen to Amazon-created queue items, you'll probably need to not use the Laravel queue system for it and access SQS via the AWS SDK for PHP directly.

Comment: Yes, that's my thought, too. Thank you!